Issue with Creating Matches in Swipe Function Using Firebase Firestore
Description
I am working on a swipe functionality in a Flutter app using Firebase Firestore. The goal is to create a match when two users swipe right on each other. However, the match is not being created as expected even though the swipe data appears to be saved correctly.
Problem
When two users swipe right on each other, a match should be created in the Firestore matches collection. Despite having both users swipe right on each other, the match document is not created.
Code
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:appinio_swiper/appinio_swiper.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SwipeHandler {
  final BuildContext context;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> profiles;
  final AppinioSwiperController controller;

  SwipeHandler(this.context, this.profiles, this.controller);

  void handleSwipe(int index, SwiperActivity activity) async {
    final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (currentUser == null) return;

    final swipedUserId = profiles[index]['uid'];

    if (activity is Swipe) {
      final startOffset = activity.begin;
      final endOffset = activity.end;

      if (startOffset != null && endOffset != null) {
        final xDiff = endOffset.dx - startOffset.dx;
        final yDiff = endOffset.dy - startOffset.dy;

        if (xDiff.abs() > yDiff.abs()) {
          if (xDiff > 0) {
            await _onSwipeRight(swipedUserId);
          } else {
            await _onSwipeLeft(swipedUserId);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _onSwipeRight(String swipedUserId) async {
    final currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final swipeRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('swipes')
        .doc(currentUserId)
        .collection('swipedUsers')
        .doc(swipedUserId);
    final otherSwipeRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('swipes')
        .doc(swipedUserId)
        .collection('swipedUsers')
        .doc(currentUserId);

    try {
      final swipeDoc = await swipeRef.get();
      final otherSwipeDoc = await otherSwipeRef.get();

      await swipeRef.set({
        'liked': true,
        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
      print('Swipe right action saved for $currentUserId on $swipedUserId');

      if (swipeDoc.data()?['liked'] == true &&
          otherSwipeDoc.exists &&
          otherSwipeDoc.data()?['liked'] == true) {
        print('Both users have swiped right');
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('matches').add({
          'user1': currentUserId,
          'user2': swipedUserId,
          'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        });
        print('Match created between $currentUserId and $swipedUserId');
        await _sendMatchNotification(swipedUserId);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error handling swipe right: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _onSwipeLeft(String swipedUserId) async {
    final currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final swipeRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('swipes')
        .doc(currentUserId)
        .collection('swipedUsers')
        .doc(swipedUserId);

    try {
      await swipeRef.set({
        'liked': false,
        'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
      print('Swipe left action saved for $currentUserId on $swipedUserId');
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error handling swipe left: $e");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _sendMatchNotification(String swipedUserId) async {
    final userSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(swipedUserId)
        .get();

    final swipedUserName = userSnapshot.data()?['name'] ?? 'User';

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('It\'s a Match!'),
          content: Text('You and $swipedUserName have liked each other!'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Start Chat'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                // Navigate to chat screen or handle chat start here
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Keep Swiping'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


Issue
Data Exists:
When I inspect the Firestore database, I can see that the swipe data is being correctly saved for both users.
No Match Created: Even though both users have swiped right on each other, a match document is not created in the matches collection.
Debug Output: The console prints indicate that swipe data is saved correctly, but the condition to check if both users swiped right seems not to be met.
Troubleshooting Steps
Verified Firestore document structure and data.
Ensured Firestore security rules are set to allow read and write access (temporarily set to allow read, write: if true).
Added detailed logging to inspect the data and conditions being evaluated.
What I Have Tried
Debugging the Firestore data and ensuring that the liked field is correctly set and retrieved.
Manually checking Firestore for the existence of swipe documents.
Testing with mock data to ensure the match logic works.
What I Need Help With
Identifying why the match is not being created despite the swipe data being correct.
Suggestions for additional debugging steps or potential issues with the current logic.
